# Unable to rename JSX tags in Visual Studio Code using F2

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a React project using Visual Studio Code and I've encountered an issue with renaming JSX tags. I'm trying to rename tags in a .jsx file using the F2 shortcut, but every time I try this, I receive an error message stating "Cannot rename this element."

Here's what I've tried so far to resolve the issue:

I have the Babel JavaScript extension installed and enabled.

I've added a jsconfig.json file to the root of my project with the following configuration:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I've ensured that both VS Code and all of my extensions are updated to the latest versions.

I've attempted to disable all other extensions that might potentially interfere with the rename function, including any formatting or linting extensions.

Despite these attempts, the issue persists. I'm unable to rename JSX tags using the F2 shortcut in any of my .jsx files, not just a specific one.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or know why this might be happening? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.